# Do multiple attacks from a multiattack action have to happen in order?

Tags: dnd-5e, multiattack

Let's assume a Giant Crocodile is trying to defend its life against an angry but solitary PC. This Crocodile intends to use its Multiattack power as an action

> Multiattack: The crocodile makes two attacks: one with its bite and one with its tail.

Now here's the catch: its bite has a chance to grab its foe, and its tail can't target grabbed foes. Thus the crocodile would like to start with its tail attack and follow with its bite.

Can it do that or does it have to stick with the order as written (bite, then tail)?

Comment: I suspect the *intent* is that a crocodile could swat a target to its rear or side while simultaneously biting a target in front of it. I can't picture a crocodile doing the kind of tactical thinking needed to maneuver itself to swat and bite the same target in the same round.

Comment: @chepner Some monsters (like the t-rex) specifically state that their attacks have to target different opponents. This giant crocodile doesn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No, they do not have to happen in the order mentioned in the sentence.

Generally in 5e, if there is a requirement, it will be stated explicitly. There is no statement here about the tail attack happening *after* the bite attack, and therefore, it doesn't need to be.

Compare for example how the **panther** can make a bite attack with a bonus action only if it has already knocked a target prone with a claw attack on that same turn:

> **Pounce.** If the panther moves at least 20 ft. straight toward a creature and then hits it with a claw attack on the same turn, that target must succeed on a DC 12 Strength saving throw or be knocked prone. If the target is prone, the panther can make one bite attack against it as a bonus action.

Because there is no such action economy written into the Giant Crocodile's multiattack description, you don't have to worry about it. The beast can make those individual attacks in any order.